# Why doesnt this simple keras model converge?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

The loss function doesn’t approach 0. It doesn’t seem to converge, and consistently can’t predict Y.
I've tried playing with the initializer, activation and layer sizes. Any insight here would be appreciated.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

activation = 'relu'
initializer = 'he_uniform'
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,),batch_size=1)
dense_layer = keras.layers.Dense(
    32,
    activation=activation,
    kernel_initializer=initializer
)(input_layer)
dense_layer = keras.layers.Dense(
    32,
    activation=activation,
    kernel_initializer=initializer
)(dense_layer)
predictions = keras.layers.Dense(1)(
    dense_layer
)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[predictions])
model.summary()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)

x = tf.constant([[727.], [1424.], [379], [1777], [51.]])
y = tf.constant([[1.], [1.], [0.], [1.], [0.]])
for item in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y)).shuffle(5).repeat():

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        x = item[0]
        output = model(x)
        loss = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(
            from_logits=True
        )(item[1], output)
        # loss = item[1] - output[0]
        dy_dx = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(dy_dx, model.trainable_weights))
        print("batch", item[0], "x",  "output", output, "expected", item[1], "gradient", dy_dx[-1])

        print("loss", loss)
```

Comment: You need to be more explicit than "nothing seems to work", people cannot guess what the problem is and what happens when you run the code.

Comment: Ah. The loss function doesn’t approach 0. It doesn’t seem to converge.

Comment: You need to make your loss and outputs compatible, what is the task here? Liner activation does not match binary crossentropy

Comment: I updated the loss for sigmoid. Though from_logits should handle any input? 

The thing that’s seeming to work, is switching from he_uniform to uniform. Which is odd to me.

Comment: That does not answer what I asked about the task.

Comment: The task is Binary Classification. I fully expect/want this model to overfit. But loss doesn’t decrease unless I use ‘uniform’ weight initialization. Is that what you’re looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input numbers are huge which leads to numerical issues, and you are not batching your inputs which leads to each batch producing very large gradients (again, due to the large input numbers) in possibly different directions. It works fine when I

- Add `.batch(5)` to the dataset definition (in fact, just replaced `shuffle` because every batch contains the full dataset) to improve the gradient estimates,
- Divide the inputs by 1000 to get them in a more reasonable range,
- After that you can increase the learning rate (something as high as 0.1 works fine) to speed up the training significantly.

This should converge very quickly.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

activation = 'relu'
initializer = 'he_uniform'
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
dense_layer = keras.layers.Dense(
    32,
    activation=activation,
    kernel_initializer=initializer
)(input_layer)
dense_layer = keras.layers.Dense(
    32,
    activation=activation,
    kernel_initializer=initializer
)(dense_layer)
predictions = keras.layers.Dense(1)(
    input_layer
)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[predictions])
model.summary()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)

x = tf.constant([[727.], [1424.], [379], [1777], [51.]]) / 1000.
y = tf.constant([[1.], [1.], [0.], [1.], [0.]])
for step, item in enumerate(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y)).batch(5).repeat()):

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        x = item[0]
        output = model(x)
        loss = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(
            from_logits=True
        )(item[1], output)
        # loss = item[1] - output[0]
        dy_dx = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(dy_dx, model.trainable_weights))
        if not step % 100:
            print("batch", item[0], "x",  "output", tf.nn.sigmoid(output), "expected", item[1], "gradient", dy_dx[-1])
            print("loss", loss)
```

And note: You using *no* activation function with a binary cross-entropy "from logits" is correct, so ignore people telling you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your output layer - `predictions` - is missing an activation. [`keras.layers.Dense`](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/) has a default value of `None` for the `activation` parameter. From your code it looks like you are doing binary classification, therefore your output layer should have a `'sigmoid'` activation.

On inference be sure to round the output of the model to 0 or 1 to get the predictions.

Comment: I believe an activation of None defaults to a linear activation, which should work? Nonetheless, I tried this and still no luck.